# CSS Reset Leaving Margins

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to HTML/CSS, currently working through the "Interneting is Hard" HTML course. I've just got to using the universal selector to reset default margins, but I'm still getting a margin around my webpage. I'm using Firefox, if that helps.

For clarification, I've added in:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

(border and background color added for debugging)

[These are the borders I was not expecting to see (in yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4JL4.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your code is working fine. The element inside must be having padding or margin

Comment: Using firefox inspector you should be able to see what is adding the margin / padding

Comment: Another thing that maybe causing this is CSS Specificity - that is the order your styling rules are applied. I.e. if you have some contradicting CSS below this * part, it will overwrite the conflicting parts.

Comment: I've solved it... I forgot I had another stylesheet attached to the page... feeling kinda dumb now. Thanks for all your advice though! Thank you @MartijnICU, checking the inspector, I noticed the other stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

`*` - is universal selector and he will add style for everyone element on site. `html` tag , `body` tag, `.all_classes` , `#all_id` , `all_tags` has this styles. This is not good.
In your case every element will have `background: yellow;` etc.

Use only global attributes in this selector like `user-select` or `border-box`

Or for example you want add styles for some elements inside some tag , class or id

```
.some-class * {
  font-size: 20px
}

#some-id * {
  font-size: 20px
}

some-tag * {
  font-size: 20px
}
```